Issue with moveit task constructor: min_fraction not met. Achieved: 0.090909 failed to move full distance
I am using ros noetic to control a robotic arm.  I have written a script to test the functionality of moveit task constructor, but I am getting the following output from launching the script:
`NODES
/
task_constructor_demo (my_mtc_pkg/task_constructor_demo)
auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [299786]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311
setting /run_id to 5585739a-34ec-11ef-8a20-ada96df89d57
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [299796]
started core service [/rosout]
process[task_constructor_demo-2]: started with pid [299803]
[ INFO] [1719537513.006376266]: Loading robot model 'khi_cx165l'...
0  - ←   0 →   -  0 / Cartesian Path
1  - ←   1 →   -  0 / initial state
-  0 →   0 →   -  0 / x +0.005
-  0 →   0 ←   1  - / connect
1  - ←   1 →   -  1 / final state
Failing stage(s):
x +0.005 (0/1): min_fraction not met. Achieved: 0.090909
failed to move full distance
[ERROR] [1719537513.197906878]: Planning failed
`
The test code is as follows:
#include <moveit/task_constructor/task.h>
#include <moveit/task_constructor/stages/fixed_state.h>
#include <moveit/task_constructor/solvers/cartesian_path.h>
#include <moveit/task_constructor/solvers/joint_interpolation.h>
#include <moveit/task_constructor/stages/move_to.h>
#include <moveit/task_constructor/stages/move_relative.h>
#include <moveit/task_constructor/stages/connect.h>

#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <moveit/planning_scene/planning_scene.h>

using namespace moveit::task_constructor;

Task createTask() {
    Task t;
    t.stages()->setName("Cartesian Path");

    const std::string group = "manipulator";  // Planning group name

    // create Cartesian interpolation "planner" to be used in various stages
    auto cartesian_interpolation = std::make_shared<solvers::CartesianPath>();
    cartesian_interpolation->setProperty("max_velocity_scaling_factor", 0.1); //          Reduce speed if needed
    cartesian_interpolation->setProperty("max_acceleration_scaling_factor", 0.1); // Reduce acceleration if needed
    cartesian_interpolation->setProperty("timeout", 60.0);  // Set a 60-second timeout

// create a joint-space interpolation "planner" to be used in various stages
auto joint_interpolation = std::make_shared<solvers::JointInterpolationPlanner>();

// start from a fixed robot state
t.loadRobotModel();
auto scene = std::make_shared<planning_scene::PlanningScene>(t.getRobotModel());
{
    auto& state = scene->getCurrentStateNonConst();
    state.setToDefaultValues(state.getJointModelGroup(group), "home");  // Set to the 'home' state

    auto fixed = std::make_unique<stages::FixedState>("initial state");
    fixed->setState(scene);
    t.add(std::move(fixed));
}

{
    auto stage = std::make_unique<stages::MoveRelative>("x +0.005", cartesian_interpolation);  // Further reduce the distance
    stage->setGroup(group);
    geometry_msgs::Vector3Stamped direction;
    direction.header.frame_id = "base_link";  // Change frame to match your robot's base frame
    direction.vector.x = 0.005;  // Move an even smaller distance along the x-axis
    stage->setDirection(direction);
    stage->setIKFrame("link6");  // Set the IK frame to the tip link of your manipulator
    stage->setProperty("min_fraction", 0.01);  // Allow partial success if 1% of the path is found
    t.add(std::move(stage));
}

{  // move from reached state back to the original state, using joint interpolation
    stages::Connect::GroupPlannerVector planners = { { group, joint_interpolation } };
    auto connect = std::make_unique<stages::Connect>("connect", planners);
    t.add(std::move(connect));
}

{  // final state is original state again
    auto fixed = std::make_unique<stages::FixedState>("final state");
    fixed->setState(scene);
    t.add(std::move(fixed));
}

return t;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    ros::init(argc, argv, "mtc_tutorial");
    ros::AsyncSpinner spinner(1);
    spinner.start();

    Task t = createTask();

    try {
        if (t.plan()) {
        ROS_INFO("Planning successful");
    } else {
        ROS_ERROR("Planning failed");
    }
} catch (const std::exception& e) {
    ROS_ERROR_STREAM("Exception caught: " << e.what());
    return 1;
}

ros::waitForShutdown();
return 0;

}
